# Unity build won't run

Tags: dll, build, unity-game-engine, binary

For some reason none of my projects in unity will build.  When I place the build outside of the asset file, it just doesn't run, but when I place it in the asset folder, I get these three errors:
Assembly DLL name is reserved for internal use:

```
 Assets/play1_Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll (did files generated by a build accidentally end up in your Assets/ folder?)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Assembly DLL name is reserved for internal use: Assets/play1_Data/Managed/mscorlib.dll (did files generated by a build accidentally end up in your Assets/ folder?)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:error CS2015: Source file `Assets/play1_Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll' is a binary file and not a text file
```

Comment: Don't put your builds in your assets folder. But if it doesn't work when you build it in an outside folder, inform us as to what happens and what problems you encounter.

Comment: it doesn't work outside the asset folder either, but there are no errors.  it just doesn't run

Comment: Does't run? Nothing at all? Not even the initial window asking you for the screen resolution? Are all files present? That is, even the  xxxx_Data directory? If that is all fine, check the player logs to see if they contain any further information http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html